# String de conexión dinámico

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el valor catalog de mi `string` de conexión sea dinámico?
¿Es posible esto?

```
<add name="conexionCopia" connectionString="Data
Source=000.00.00.00;Initial Catalog=esto_quiero_hacer_dinamico;User
Id=sa;Password=0000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

¿Dejarlo con algún tipo de variable ?

Cualquier ayuda me servirá para buscar información saludos.

Comment: eso es tu archivo de configuracion?

Comment: si es el archivo de conexion

Comment: Quieres que cambie el valor en el archivo de configuración?

Comment: Podrías colocar varias cadenas de conexión y seleccionar la que desees en tu capa de datos de acuerdo a la condición que tengas

Comment: No se si se puede realizar dicha operación, lo que utilizo cuando tengo varios connectionString, es colocar todas las posibilidades, comentarlas e ir habilitando a medida que voy necesitando.

Comment: viste esto? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir la base de datos desde la aplicación, podrías usar esta aproximación:

```
<add name="conexionCopia" connectionString="Data Source=000.00.00.00;Initial Catalog={0};User ID=sa;Password=0000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

> **Nota el** `{0}` **en el *InitialCatalog***.

Cuando vayas a consumir la base de datos, puedes prepararla fácilmente de la siguiente manera:

```
string bd = "NombreDeTuBd";
string cnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionCopia"].ToString();

// string.Format reemplazará el primer argumento en la ubicación de {0}:
cnstr = string.Format(cnstr, bd);

// El resultado será
// "Data Source=000.00.00.00;Initial Catalog=NombreDeTuBd;User ID=sa;Password=0000"
```

Así solo tendrás que tener el nombre de la base de datos a la que quieras apuntar y podrás utilizar la misma cadena de conexión.

---

Yo personalmente prefiero dejar TODO lo que respecta a las bd en el archivo de configuración, por lo que tengo varias cadenas de conexión:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="...Settings.bd1" connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=BD1;User ID=...;Password=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="...Settings.bd2" connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=BD2;User ID=...;Password=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Y administrar todas las conexiones a través de una clase dedicada a ello:

```
public class DbLink : IDisposable
{
    private int _Segundos;
    private SqlConnection _SQL;
    private bool disposed = false;
    public const int TIEMPO_DE_CONEXION_DEFAULT = 40;

    public DbLink()
    {
        SetTime(TIEMPO_DE_CONEXION_DEFAULT);
    }

    public enum DB
    {
        DB1,
        DB2
    };

    public void SetTime(int Segundos) => _Segundos = Segundos;

    private void CreateConnection(DB bdd) => _SQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[string.Concat("...Settings.", SelectDb(bdd))].ToString());

    private string SelectDb(DB bdd)
    {
        if (bdd == DB.DB1)
            return "bd1";
        return "bd2";
    }

    public DataTable QueryToTable(DB DBase, string Consulta)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        CreateConnection(DBase);
        using (SqlConnection DBCon = _SQL)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(Consulta, DBCon))
            {
                DBCon.Open();
                cmnd.CommandTimeout = _Segundos;
                cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd))
                {
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public DataSet ExecuteSPSet(DB DBase, string procedimiento, params SqlParameter[] datos)
    {
        CreateConnection(DBase);
        using (SqlConnection con = _SQL)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(Procedimiento, con))
            {
                cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmnd.CommandTimeout = _Segundos;
                cmnd.Parameters.AddRange(datos);
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    con.Close();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_SQL is SqlConnection)
                {
                    _SQL.Close();
                    _SQL.Dispose();
                }
                _IsActiveUser = false;
                _User = String.Empty;
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_SQL is SqlConnection)
        {
            _SQL.Close();
            _SQL.Dispose();
        }
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Ese código (coloqué solo el método para extraer una tabla de datos de consulta) me permite usar las bases de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
using (DbLink link = new DbLink)
{
    DataTable resultsDb1 = link.QueryToTable(DbLink.DB1, "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS");
    DataTable resultsDb2 = link.QueryToTable(DbLink.DB2, "SELECT * FROM TablaRandom");
}
```

Cabe mencionar que también recomiendo *por lo menos* usar un constructor de sentencias SQL para [evitar inyecciones](https://backtrackacademy.com/articulo/inyeccion-sql-definicion-y-ejemplos) y también recomiendo usar [procedimientos almacenados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/stored-procedures-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), pero para lidiar con varias bases de datos así es como lo prefiero.

Comment: gracias me sirvió tu respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo sin problemas, pero no en tu archivo de configuración, sino en tu código de conexión que hagas en `C#` o `VB.NET`.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // el valor para este string lo puedes sacar de donde 
        // quieras: un archivo, input del usuario, una base de datos,
        // de la nube, etc, etc, etc
        string connectionString = "este_valor_puede_ser_dinamico";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // acá haces lo que necesites
        }
    }
```

Comment: en SO en español se espera cierto grado de calidad en las respuestas, esto que colocas parece mas un comentario; sería ideal si colocas el como se va a hacer pues asi a todos incluidos futuros usuarios les quedará mas claro

Comment: en este comunidad para mejorar todos podemos comentar asi funciona te sugiero revises mejor los enlaces [answer] y [tour]

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz lo que te indico alfredo era correcto. Al principio la respuesta solo parecia un comentario al no tener nada de codigo. Ahora la respuesta esta bien. Sin embargo la forma en que te condujiste con Alfredo no es correcta. No hizo mas que decirte que de esa forma la respuesta bien podria haberse puesto como comentario. El sitio tiene reglas, y tienes reputacion como para saber como funciona.. Una de las reglas es se cortez. El solo recalco que mejoraras la respuesta.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz yo no soy moderador y no tengo acceso a borrar tus comentarios ni nada por el estilo. Sabes como funciona el sitio, y si tus comentarios han sido borrados lo habra hecho un moderador si los mismos fueron reportados.

Comment: si tienes problemas con la moderacion, podemos hablarlo en el [chat]

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta pero no entiendo donde seteo ese valor para hacerlo dinamico ?

Comment: @Hector en ese caso, deberías explicarnos a qué llamas "dinámico"